How to import a broken (content-wise) MySQL dump?
I'm trying to import a dump, but I'm getting syntax errors that kills the import. The problem is, I can fix the errors on the source DB, but I can neither see them all at once nor ignore the errors with "-f". Is there a way to see all the errors at once? I've adjust the charset and collation but errors still occur, the original database is kind of a mess. I get errors like this one:

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6613: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Sistema vinculou responsavel em 20/06/2023 15:27:13 Sistema vin' at line 1

I can only dump the DB at night to not slow down the production, and that makes the process a lot slower.
I've tried changing the names to latin1 on the dump file, (as is on the original DB) but it did not help.
I am using the mysqldump db > db.sql command to create the dump and using mysql db < db.sql to import it.
The original DB is on MySQL 5.5.46. I've tried to import it on a MySQL Server 5.5.46 and 8.0.
The syntax is broken because of a single quote, but it's also been broken with /n and a lot of other symbol/syntax problems. The dump file is quite large at 4GB.

I don't think there's a way to see all the errors. MySQL stops reading the file as soon as it gets an error.

I've never heard of getting errors like this if you're loading back into the same version of MySQL. Errors are usually due to version incompatibilities.

This error looks like a comment in the dump file is missing the /* before it.

The version is exactly the same 5.5.46-0+deb8u1 (changing the fact that i am using Debian 12 and Ubuntu 24.04 on my test)
That error above has a ' (single quote) not escaped that was the error, i trying to go error by error, but i guess that will take me some years at this point.
I've split the file in 512mb pieces and i'm editing it on vim.

Mysqldump should escape properly, but if that old version has a bug that causes it to not escape a single quote, then you could use a newer mysqldump client and produce a correct dump file. That would be much faster than hand-editing many megabytes of dump files!

Thanks @BillKarwin, i do think that did the trick.
I Did the dump using the 8.0 MySQL client, the dump was imported without error, i did not validate the data yet. the only thing that concern me, is the size of the dump, the original DB is 4GB, my new dump is 11GB and my new database is 11GB after importing as well.
